# Applying a function in a nested context to a value in a nested context in haskell

Tags: haskell, lambda-calculus

Consider the following Applicative context f. I have a list of functions wrapped around this context F = f [a -> a] and a list of values wrapped around the same context i.e. V = f [a]. Now I want to apply the functions in F to the values in V. How can this be achieved?

I have tried the following :

```
1. (F <*>) <*> V
2. (V <*>) (F <*>)
```

But for some reason the types won't match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The types won't match in 1 because both `<*>`s are at the same "layer", and they won't match in 2 because you're trying to call the values as functions. (There are other problems too, but that should be enough to see why they shouldn't work.) You're looking for one of these two expressions:

```
(<*>) <$> f <*> v
liftA2 (<*>) f v
```

And remember in Haskell, variables start with lowercase letters and data constructors start with uppercase letters.

Answer (score 1):

This is not simpler than just using `liftA2`, but it's interesting to note that the composition of two applicative functors is itself an applicative functor.

```
> import Data.Functor.Compose
> getCompose $ Compose (Just [(+1)]) <*> Compose (Just [5])
Just [6]
> getCompose $ Compose ([Just (+1)]) <*> Compose ([Just 5])
[Just 6]
```

The order in which `<*>` "digs into" its operands is inferred from (or defined by) the type of the wrapped value. For example,

```
> :t Compose [Just 'c']
Compose [Just 'c'] :: Compose [] Maybe Char
> :t Compose (Just ['c'])
Compose (Just ['c']) :: Compose Maybe [] Char
```